# android emulator not launching my project

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am creating a new project. I am running the app with "Run without debuging" and selecting the emulator "pixel XL API 30".
The icons of the emulator (plaz, reload, hot reload...) show up for 5 seconds and then disappear. The Vscode is not launching the app.

In the debug console I get the following error: "Exited (1)"
Unable to locate adb

I run flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Someone know why can I not see my project in the emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: does the app run on a connected device?

Comment: Have you configured the emulator in Android Studio before running the app with it in VSCode?

Comment: yes, the app is connected to the device

Comment: yes I did configured in Android Studio